# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad pattern character 'E' in EE,dd MMM yyyy

Tags: java, android

I am working on android application where I am using simonvt datepicker library because of backward compatible but I see in my developer console crash report there are 3 reports for this same error but this I tried in my device that is working so this is really weird.

Please support for this why it so strange and getting java exception sometime.

```
OnDateSetListener date = new OnDateSetListener() {

    private void updateLabel() {

        String myFormat = "EEE, dd MMM"; // In which you need put here
        String myDbFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        SimpleDateFormat DBsdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myDbFormat, Locale.US);
        Departure_date = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());
        Departure_date_url = DBsdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());

        Log.i("Departure_date", Departure_date);
        date_btn.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(net.simonvt.datepicker.DatePicker view, int year,
            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    }
};


final net.simonvt.datepicker.DatePickerDialog dpd = new net.simonvt.datepicker.DatePickerDialog(
                            getActivity(), date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Logcat :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad pattern character 'E' in EE,dd MMM yyyy
at libcore.icu.ICU.getDateFormatOrder(ICU.java:165)
at android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormatOrder(DateFormat.java:388)
at net.simonvt.datepicker.DatePicker.reorderSpinners(DatePicker.java:515)
at net.simonvt.datepicker.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:284)
at net.simonvt.datepicker.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:149)
... 22 more
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code shows `String myFormat = "EEE, dd MMM"` whereas the error message tells us "Bad pattern character 'E' in EE,dd MMM yyyy". _Patterns don't match._ Either your code is not up to date, or the error is in another place. I assume the latter beacause the exception stack trace is showing the method `libcore.icu.ICU.getDateFormatOrder`. There is no SDF involved.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose sometime it throws an exception this `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad pattern character 'E' in E, MMM d, yyyy
`

Comment: Cool. Simply ignoring the two possibilities I made explicit to you is ... somewhat ... _ignorant_. Especially, when _throwing in_ an exception that still does not match the code.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose this is really weird

Comment: Check these links : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993132/getting-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-illegal-pattern-character-o-while & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861976/exception-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-20-error-infla

Answer (score -1):

Base on your log `Bad pattern character 'E' in EE,dd MMM yyyy`.

I occured `EE,dd MMM yyyy`. But, your code have `String myFormat = "EEE, dd MMM";`. What was wrong with you.

```
"EEE, MMM d, ''yy" --> Wed, Jul 4, '01
```

[SimpleDateFormat](http://metadata-training-centre.blogspot.com/2014/06/using-simpledateformat.html)

Comment: I didn't get your answer sorry

Comment: The problem with that answer: A `SimpleDateFormat` can be constructed with the pattern "EE,dd MMM yyyy". So, unfortunately this doesn't answer the question.